# Is anyone using Google Group Integration for CiviCRM?

Tags: extension, groups, integration

We have tried implementing [Google Group Integration for CiviCRM](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.googlegroup) - we got 90% there [but ran into issues](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.googlegroup/issues/14).  We have some funds to get a fix - but we have not heard from the developer.  Is anyone using this extension successfully?

Answer (score 3):

I have a [forked version](https://github.com/pradpnayak/uk.co.vedaconsulting.googlegroup) of the [primary repository](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.googlegroup) where i have updated the code to support latest version of api. This is hasn't been tested since 2 years.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep - I tried installing and I keep getting: "DB Error: already exists"
I tried manually dropping all tables I could find related to the install - thinking that was the issue - but maybe I am missing some - any idea?

Comment: Okay than it may require some minor fixes i think